# How to set up IntelliJIdea for development using JOGL on Linux and Windows?

Tags: java, linux, windows, intellij-idea, jogl

I am developing a game in Linux and Windows using IntelliJIdea. I always had a good experience with simultaneous development on both systems, where all project files are stored locally on a shared partition, but now I cannot configure this IDE to work with JOGL libraries on both operating systems.

Yesterday, JOGL functioned well in Linux, after which I used Windows to compile and run the project. When I returned to Linux, all the paths to jar files and sources were in Windows format and were unusable in Linux.

Is there a way to configure the IDE for simultaneous development?

Comment: What specific paths are you referring to? Project/library paths are stored relatively and unless you specify the paths explicitly somewhere, the project files are cross compatible between all the operating systems.

Comment: They turned into D:\...\...

Comment: Please be more specific about "they". Add screenshots to your question that would show what paths in UI were changed.

Comment: I managed to use the library on both systems after I copied all the required files in a single folder where the project files are. I was adding them as module dependencies -> java libraries in Jar form, one by one according to the tutorial. They would become listed as libraries in Project Structure. But when I looked the other day at the dependencies, they were like !cannot find path D:/.../... and IntelliJIdea updated itself to 13.0.1.

Answer (score 1):

Use Maven to handle the dependencies (they're available on maven central):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jogamp.gluegen</groupId>
    <artifactId>gluegen-rt-main</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jogamp.jogl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jogl-all-main</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jogamp.jogl</groupId>
    <artifactId>newt</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Works for me