# Cannot Get JOGL to run, compiles fine but error during execution

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jogl

I followed the installation here:

http://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Setting_up_a_JogAmp_project_in_your_favorite_IDE#IntelliJ_IDEA

and

http://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Downloading_and_installing_JOGL

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA Community 13. Everything compiles nicely but when i go to run the code i get the error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.helljogl.OneTriangleSwingGLJPanel
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
>     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
>     at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
>     at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:113)

I have OpenGL and Java experience, but for some reason this is giving me a huge headache. 
I've been at it for hours and have seen similar problems, but found no solutions...
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than adding the dependencies to the project through the IDE, use maven (or Gradle). There's no need to manually download the jogl jar files and mess around with your classpath. See [How to set up IntelliJIdea for development using JOGL on Linux and Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20644868/how-to-set-up-intellijidea-for-development-using-jogl-on-linux-and-windows/20922993#20922993)

Comment: That's eventually what I wound up doing. Maven makes life better lol ^_^y

Answer (score 1):

After so many Installation Attempts I had jogl.jars all over the place. After cleaning up my environment everything is going smoothly!